# How to reduce the C++ standard library libstdc++.so file size

Tags: c++

I have different C++ compilers on my computer, each compiler has its own libstdc++.so and their size is different.

```
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 967K Mar 22  2017 libstdc++.so.6.0.13
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 6.5M Aug  1  2017 libstdc++.so.6.0.20
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root  11M Aug  1  2017 libstdc++.so.6.0.21
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root  12M Jan 30 16:58 libstdc++.so.6.0.24
```

I want to know why libstdc++.so.6.0.13 is so much smaller than others, and is there any way to reduce others' size.
I will be glad if some one can help me.

Comment: Why don't you provide a lot more information about your specific setup?

Comment: I think this is a fair question - why such a difference.

Comment: @rustyx who knows?  We don't have any information on how it came to be or any way to reproduce it.

Comment: The size of `libstdc++.so` can depend on how they are linked (statically/dynamically). Can you post `ldd` output for each library?

Comment: Why do you care about that size? In practice, the C++ standard library shared object is shared between many processes using it, so its size is not very important!

Answer (score 9):

The versioning scheme of libstdc++ is misleading, the differences between these versions are actually huge when you consider the corresponding GCC versions:

- GCC 4.4.2: libstdc++.so.6.0.13 (October 15, 2009)
- GCC [4.9.0](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.9/changes.html): libstdc++.so.6.0.20 (April 22, 2014)
- GCC [5.1.0](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-5/changes.html): libstdc++.so.6.0.21 (April 22, 2015)
- GCC [7.2.0](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-7/changes.html): libstdc++.so.6.0.24 (August 14, 2017)

There's been the C++14 implementation between GCC 4.4 and 4.9, and major work on C++17 and various experimental proposals after that.

From libstdc++'s [FAQ](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/faq.html#faq.size):

> Usually the size of libraries on disk isn't noticeable...
>
> . . . the object files
> in question contain template classes and template functions,
> pre-instantiated, and splitting those up causes severe maintenance
> headaches.

So in short - not much can be done about the size. If you're *really* interested, you can see what's inside using `readelf -a libname.so`

You can always downgrade to an older GCC version which will come with a smaller libstdc++.

Having said that, on Ubuntu the size of `libstdc++.so.6.0.24` is [1.54MB](https://reposcope.com/package/libstdc++6/files), so it didn't actually grow that much. There could be something wrong with your specific distro or maybe you grabbed a debug version. You can try stripping debug symbols with `strip libstdc++.so.6.0.24` (the `strip` utility is part of `binutils`).

Comment: oh, thanks a lot! `strip` command helps reduce the size of  `libstdc++.so.6.0.24` to 1.6MB